# Only first test case succeeds - Jasmine/Karma in Angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test an angular component by using Jasmine/Karma. When I run my test scripts for this component only first test case succeeds, remaining all getting error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coSearchCriteria' of undefined thrown".

and I can switch the order of the test methods and the first one will always pass, even if it failed the last run. If I run these test cases one by one all will pass. But problem coming while testing the entire component through 'ng test'.

This similar way I have tested remaining components also but those are all working fine.

Comment: Looks like your component is sharing something in static way thus recreating it has no meaningfull effect..

Comment: Please provide all of your related component code.

Comment: @trichetriche Thanks for reply. Updated, 'coSearchCriteria'  this is the error which I am getting, this is used in this file only.

Comment: `this.store.select(selectorCOCriteriaState)
    .subscribe((coSearchCriteria: SearchCriteriaState)` → you didn't mock your store service, so it behaves poorly and you can't control it. Mock it to have full control over it.

Comment: @trichetriche Is it, If you don't mind could you please give me a clarity, where and how to mock, either test file or class file need to be mock. Basically I am new to Angular, Thank you.

Comment: I then suggest you [read their guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing) which explains everything in details on how it works and why you should do that.

Comment: @trichetriche Thank you so much for your help and I will go through this definitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mock your ngrx store in spec file.While testing any store need to be mock that store.

```js
class MockStore {
  public dispatch(obj) {
    console.log('dispatching from the mock store!')
  }

  public select(obj) {
    console.log('selecting from the mock store!');

    return Observable.of({})
  }
}
```